# Multiple inheritance of exception classes

Tags: c++, exception, multiple-inheritance

I got a trouble designing the hierarchy of exception classes in my program component.
There are several failure cases (that belong to, say, `std::bad_alloc`, `std::invalid_argument`, `std::system_error`, etc...) in this component, and for each very specific failure case I made the corresponding exception class, deriving from the above general exception categories.

Now, I was requested to make all of my exception classes derived from a single class, say `Base`, so that my client can know if the failure is from my component or not by simply catching `Base`. However, there is another client of my component who is not interested on where the exception occurred but on why it has occurred. So it seems that my exception classes must derive both from general standard exception classes as well as the single distinguished base class `Base`.

My question is: should I make `Base` derived from `std::exception`?

If it is derived from std::exception, then there must be two std::exception instances inside each exception class, since it seems that the standard exception classes are not using virtual inheritance. I think I must write the conversion operator into `std::exception` in this case for each exception class, and that seems very tedious.

If it is not derived from std::exception, then the client who only wants to catch `Base` can't use the abilities of std::exception, e.g., `what()`, unless I implement them inside the base class. If that is the case, all the exception classes are essentially having two names for a single ability, and that seems ridiculous. Also, if the client wishes to rethrow it to others who are expecting exception classes deriving from `std::exception`, the client must do some form of repacking, which is quite undesirable.

What should I do?

**Edit:**
The request of the second client is that he/she wants to use the standard exception classes rather than what I've made, because there are very many components he/she is using, simultaneously throwing too many kinds of exceptions, so he/she just can't be aware of all the failure cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can - don't have to - derive from `std::exception`. If you do, inherit virtually. It'll be a little bit slower - but not noticeable next to the inevitable try-catch.

Also note that, based on what you wrote, you can simply have a multi-level inheritance:

```
class Base : public std::exception { ... };
class BadAlloc : public Base { ... };
class InvalidArg : public Base { ... };
```

Edit:

Since you want to inherit a hierarchy from members of another hierarchy, you need the second as template parameter. You can inject a custom base class to that with the Base / BaseImpl paradigm:

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual int getTheMeaning() const = 0;
};

template<typename SecondBase = std::exception>
class BaseImpl : public Base, public SecondBase
{
public:
    BaseImpl(int localMeaning) : meaning_(localMeaning * 3) {}
    int getTheMeaning() const override { return meaning_; }

private:
    const int meaning_;
};

class InvalidArg : public BaseImpl<std::logic_error>
{
public:
    InvalidArg() : BaseImpl<std::logic_error>(14) {}
};
```

Then you can catch either `const std::logic_error&` or `const Base&`, which is I believe what you want. This has the advantage that `const Base&` can still have virtual functions implemented in `BaseImpl<>` and thus the explicit details can be driven by the latter.

Comment: Yes I can derive from `std::exception`, but as I said in the question, then the conversion to `std::exception` becomes ambiguous since there are two instances of `std::exception`. Virtual inheritance will not help, since e.g. `std::logic_error` does not use it.

Comment: No - if you inherit virtually, there's only one. This is called the solution to the dared diamond problem.

Comment: That only happens if all the base classes virtually inherits from the grand-base class, isn't it? In my case, `Base` can use virtual inheritance but `std::logic_error` does not use it, unfortunately.

Comment: @lorro If I am reading the OP right there situation is like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2fc65b36ef5e8168) and I do not see a way to get that to work.

Comment: Do you mean that you need to inherit from a hierarchy of classes by a hierarchy of classes, rather than from two base classes which share a third?

Comment: @NathanOliver: make the other `std::exception` virtual as well.

Comment: @lorro Good call.  Forgot about that one.

Comment: @lorro - that's the point, the other exception is a std::logic_error (for example) and isn't editable

Comment: @UKMonkey: would `class BaseImpl<typename T = std::exception> : public Base, public T {}` work for you? I.e., can you accept type erasure of the std::exception hierarcy once you've catched `const Base&` and still provide a proper `Base` interface?

Comment: I think the question that needs to be really looked into, is what functionality do you want in your base class?  If your customer wants you to use std::exception, then why not just use the std::exceptions available & any other that you want that inherit just std::exception?

Comment: @UKMonkey Well, I'll ask the client code's author, but I think he at least wants to be able to figure out if the error has originated by the user's fault (e.g., an invalid argument is given), or is a kind of system failure (e.g., some peripheral device has failed), or blah blah. So perhaps It would be better to derive from `std::invalid_argument` or others than just derive directly from `std::exception`.

Comment: @lorro I couldn't follow what you mean. What's the difference between your solution and just not making `Base` be derived from `std::exception`?

Comment: @JunekeyJeon: `Base` is not derived from `std::exception` here as well. However here, if you catch `Base&`, you can cast it to `BaseImpl<T>&` by knowing only `T`, not the actual `Base`-descendant; and `BaseImpl<T>` is a descendant of `std::exception`. Therefore, you can go from `Base&` to `T&`, sg which is impossible in the other case. Also, since you're likely to implement much of your actual exceptions in terms of `std::exception`-tree, you can do some of the specializations in `BaseImpl<T>` already.